# Move forward a sprite 2d in clicking on it in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

Unity version:2021.1.24f1

Hello, currently I am creating a 2D game with Unity 3d; I wish that when I click with my mouse and the cursor is above my sprite it goes up 15 pixels; it moves vertically and horizontally

My script:

````
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
        float m_speed;
        
    
        void Start(){
            m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            m_speed = 5f;
        }
    
        void Update()
        //bouton gauche de la souris
        {if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            m_Rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward(new Vector2(0,-1) * Time.deltaTime * m_speed, Space.World);
            
        }
        //bouton droit de la souris
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)){
            m_Rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward(new Vector2(-1, 0) * Time.deltaTime*m_speed, Space.World);
        }
        //roulette de la souris
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2)){
            m_Rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward (new Vector2(0,-1) * Time.deltaTime * m_speed, Space.World);
        }
    
            
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the mistakes that you're making is that you're using a Rigidbody component in a 2D game. You should be using a Rigidbody2D component.

The other one, making the error that you stated below is that you're using `transform.forward` as a method, when in fact it's just a *Vector3(0,0,1)*. So, if you want to go up (not forward, it's 2D), just use `transform.up` alone, or `new Vector2(0,1)` without multiplying one by the other, which *doesn't really make sense*.

You also shouldn't modify the rb.velocity value directly and *I don't know if it is even possible*. There's a built-in Unity function, `Rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2)` So try using:

```
m_Rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * Time.deltaTime * m_speed);
```

That should work.
I also don't know why you are changing the velocity/force added with time, because that will make the player go faster, and faster, but it's your code.

Comment: ok,  I'll try this by replacing 'Rigidbody' by 'Rigidbody2D'

Comment: @MikaMikashu I am not saying that this will fix your issue, just spotted an error you made in your code. If you want to get this resolved, please tell us what exactly is not working properly, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: I have an error : " error CS1955:Non invocable member 'Transform.forward' cannot be used like a method"

Comment: @MikaMikashu I updated my response

Comment: Indeed that was it, we had to put right, left, up, down instead of forward and backward. My script works;  Thanks a lot @skill347 for your help, have a good day

Comment: Glad I could help @MikaMikashu